# Sign of conservative convection coefficient in a formal (Inactive) PDE

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, hold

Consider the PDE

$$\nabla \cdot (
- \color{blue}{\texttt{c}} \;\nabla u
- \color{blue}{\texttt{alpha}} \; u) = 0
\tag{std}\label{std}
$$

where

```
c     = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
alpha = {1, 0};
```

We use the helper function from [FEM Usage Tips](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html) for extracting parsed coefficients:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
getcoeffs[eqn_] :=
  First[
    NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
      List[
        eqn,
        DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]
      ], u, Element[{x, y}, Disk[]]
    ]
  ]["FiniteElementData"]["PDECoefficientData"];
```

PDE specified with minus sign **outside** `Inactive[Times][`...`]`:

```
out =
  Inactive[Div][
    -c . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]
    - Inactive[Times][alpha, u[x, y]]
 (* ^ here *)
  , {x, y}] == 0;
```

PDE specified with minus sign **inside** `Inactive[Times][`...`]`:

```
in =
  Inactive[Div][
    -c . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]
    + Inactive[Times][-alpha, u[x, y]]
                   (* ^ here *)
  , {x, y}] == 0;
```

Intuitively one would expect these to represent the same PDE, but it turns out that they are parsed differently:

```
getcoeffs[out]["ConservativeConvectionCoefficients"] (* {{{{1}, {0}}}}  *)
getcoeffs[in]["ConservativeConvectionCoefficients"]  (* {{{{-1}, {0}}}} *)
```

Given this, I would say that the minus sign should be placed **outside** to be consistent with the standard form $\eqref{std}$.

However, I am confused by the example in [FEM Usage Tips](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html) from `In[93]` onwards (Version 11.0). The *intended* PDE is

$$\nabla \cdot (
- \color{blue}{c} \;\nabla u
+ \color{blue}{\alpha} \; u) = 0
$$

where $\color{blue}{\alpha} = \{ -x, -y \}$ (see `In[85]`). But that example effectively places the minus sign **inside** `Inactive[Times][`...`]`:

```
α    = {-x, -y};
ipde =
  Inactive[Div][
    -c . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]
    + Inactive[Times][α, u[x, y]]
  , {x, y}] == 0;
```

We get

```
getcoeffs[ipde]["ConservativeConvectionCoefficients"] (* {{{{-x}, {-y}}}} *)
```

meaning the *actual* (i.e. parsed) PDE is

\begin{align*}
  \nabla \cdot (-\color{blue}{c} \;\nabla u - \{ -x, -y \} \; u) &= 0 \\
  \nabla \cdot (-\color{blue}{c} \;\nabla u - \color{blue}{\alpha} \; u) &= 0
\end{align*}

in light of the standard form $\eqref{std}$.

> **TLDR;** I think I should put the minus sign **outside** `Inactive[Times][`...`]`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues here. First, the (minus) signs in the standard form have to be specified. If `c=1` and you want to model:

$$\nabla \cdot (
- \color{blue}{\texttt{c}} \;\nabla u) = 0
$$

the input is:

```
Inactive[Div][ -c . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 0
```

In other words the minus sign needs to specified. The same is true for `alpha`.

Now, the fact that

```
getcoeffs[out]["ConservativeConvectionCoefficients"] (* {{{{1}, {0}}}}  *)
```

is a bug that is fixed in the upcoming V12.0. The correct result is:

```
(* {{{{-1}, {0}}}}  *)
```

For now you have to use the minus sign inside (close to the coefficient). I'll also clarify that inconsistency in the tips tutorial. Sorry for the confusion.

**Summary:** if you see a minus sign in the standard equation you need to specify that sign. That is the case for both `c` and `alpha` where the minus sign in front of them needs to be part of your input. Otherwise you model

$$\nabla \cdot (
\color{blue}{\texttt{c}} \;\nabla u
+ \color{blue}{\texttt{alpha}} \; u) = 0
$$

The the corresponding `NeumannValue will also change it's signs.

Yet another way to put it: Everything you see in the standard equation has to be input by you, including the minus signs should your PDE model requite them.

Comment: Am I interpreting this correctly: in v11, the PDE `in` will correctly parse as the standard form $\eqref{std}$, and the bug lies in ``NDSolve`ProcessEquations`` (as called by `getcoeffs`) identifying `alpha` as the ConservativeConvectionCoefficient rather than `-alpha`?

Comment: @lastresort, the parser of NDSolve is broken in the `out` case. The `out` case should and will in V12 return the same as the `in` case.

Comment: @lastresort, does that help?

Comment: I'm trying to reconcile this with $\eqref{std}$. In v12, does this mean that ConservativeConvectionCoefficient is $-\color{blue}{\texttt{alpha}}$ rather than $+\color{blue}{\texttt{alpha}}$ in the same way that DiffusionCoefficient is $-\color{blue}{\texttt{c}}$ rather than $+\color{blue}{\texttt{c}}$?

Comment: @lastresort, yes, the ConservativeConvectionCoefficient behaves in the same manner as the DiffusionCoefficient.

Comment: Thank you, that clarifies everything. I've added that comment into the answer (currently awaiting peer review) but feel free to revert or edit as you see fit.

Comment: @lastresort, `-alpha` and `+alpha` confuses me so I tried to come up with other formulations; I hope they are equally good for your understanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91892/discussion-between-user21-and-lastresort)