# Reveal the formal PDE of FiniteElement

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

When `FiniteElement` method is used, the differential equations will first be transformed to certain *standard form* (named as formal PDE in recent FEM document), and it turns out to be critical to check what the *standard form* is when analyzing various issues related to FEM. Here are some examples:

[Position of discontinuous coefficient influences the solution of PDE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/131542/1871)

[How to input Robin boundary conditions for nonstandard Laplace equation?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/147089/1871)

[Sign of conservative convection coefficient in a formal (Inactive) PDE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/194356/1871)

[Stress analysis in axisymmetric bodies](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198894/1871)

The coefficient of formal PDE is available from `PDECoefficientData`, but its output is just hard to read. For example, with

```
{state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
            With[{u = u[x, y]}, {-2 D[u, y, y] - 3 D[u, x, x] == 1, 
                                 DirichletCondition[u == 0, True]}], 
            u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];

data = state["FiniteElementData"]["PDECoefficientData"];

data["All"]
(* {{{{1}}, {{{{0}, {0}}}}}, {{{{{3, 0}, {0, 2}}}}, {{{{0}, {0}}}}, {{{{0, 
  0}}}}, {{0}}}, {{{0}}}, {{{0}}}} *)
```

at hand, can you tell what's what? Can you label $d$, $c$, $\alpha$, etc. in the formal PDE

$$d\frac{\partial }{\partial t}u+\nabla \cdot (-c \nabla u-\alpha  u+\gamma ) +\beta \cdot \nabla u+ a u -f=0$$

with corresponding values, without doubt?

Can we have a function that shows the formal PDE of `FiniteElement` in a easy-to-read way? A possible (but not necessary of course) input-output in my mind:

```
showFormalPDE@With[{u = u[x, y]}, -2 D[u, y, y] - 3 D[u, x, x] == 1]
(* -1 + Inactive[Div][(-{{3, 0}, {0, 2}}.Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] == 0 *)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Coincidence had it that I needed a code to reconstruct the inactive PDE that has been parsed for a customer a few weeks back. I have then added this function to the kernel and it will be available in 12.2.

The details of the operators and their specification can be found in the documentation and @andre already added links to that documentation.

In versions after 12.2 you can use:

```
NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE
```

Else, here is the code to get the inactive PDE from the NDSolve state data:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
zeroCoefficientQ[c_] := Union[N[Flatten[c]]] === {0.}
ClearAll[GetInactivePDE]
GetInactivePDE[pdec_PDECoefficientData, vd_] := 
 Module[{lif, sif, dif, mif, hasTimeQ, tvar, vars, depVars, neqn, 
   nspace, dep, load, dload, diff, cconv, conv, react, 
   pde},
  {lif, sif, dif, mif} = pdec["All"];      

  tvar = NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[vd, "Time"];
  If[tvar === None || tvar === {}, hasTimeQ = False;
   tvar = Sequence[];, hasTimeQ = True;];
  
  vars = NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[vd, "Space"];
  depVars = NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[vd, "DependentVariables"];
  neqn = Length[depVars];
  nspace = Length[vars];
  dep = (# @@ Join[{tvar}, vars]) & /@ depVars;
  
  {load, dload} = lif;
  {diff, cconv, conv, react} = sif;
  
  load = load[[All, 1]];
  dload = dload[[All, 1, All, 1]];
  conv = conv[[All, All, 1, All]];
  cconv = cconv[[All, All, All, 1]];      

  pde = If[hasTimeQ, 
    mif[[1]].D[dep, {tvar, 2}] + dif[[1]].D[dep, tvar], 
    ConstantArray[0, {Length[dep]}]];
  
  If[! zeroCoefficientQ[diff], 
   pde += (Plus @@@ 
       Table[Inactive[
          Div][-diff[[r, c]].Inactive[Grad][dep[[c]], vars], 
         vars], {r, neqn}, {c, neqn}]);];
  
  If[! zeroCoefficientQ[cconv], 
   pde += (Plus @@@ 
       Table[Inactive[Div][-cconv[[r, c]]*dep[[c]], vars], {r, 
         neqn}, {c, neqn}]);];
  
  If[! zeroCoefficientQ[dload], 
   pde += (Inactive[Div][#, vars] & /@ dload);];
  
  If[! zeroCoefficientQ[conv], 
   pde += (Plus @@@ 
       Table[conv[[r, c]].Inactive[Grad][dep[[c]], vars], {r, 
         neqn}, {c, neqn}]);];
  
  pde += react.dep;
  
  pde -= load;
  
  pde
  ]

GetInactivePDE[state_NDSolve`StateData] := Module[{femd = state["FiniteElementData"],
   vd = state["VariableData"], pdec},
  pdec = femd["PDECoefficientData"];
  GetInactivePDE[pdec, vd]]
```

Here is an example of it's usage:

```
op = -x D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] - D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] - 1;
{state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{op == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   u, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]
   ];

pde = GetInactivePDE[state];
pde // InputForm

{-1 + {1, 0} . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}] + 
  Inactive[Div][-{{x, 0}, {0, 1}} . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}]}
```

Note, how the `x` in front of the `D` got pulled into the `Div - Grad` and how that is compensated by a convection component. See for example `FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice#588198981` that explains this behavior.

Comment: Side note: `NDSolve\`FEM\`GetInactivePDE ` is built-in in _v12.2_. (There's no separate document page for it though. )

Comment: I take the liberty to add a line making `GetInactivePDE` in this post handle `NDSolve\`StateData`, feel free to roll back if you don't like it :) .

Comment: @user21 Looking at the inactive form of the pde: The  Div-part defines the   NeumannValue    `(-{{x, 0}, {0, 1}} .  Grad [U[x, y], {x, y}])` . Is this conclusion correct? Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, yes, whatever is in the Div part defines `NeumannValue`.

Comment: @user21 Thank you, in this question [Understanding `NeumannValue`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268380/understanding-neumannvalue) I 'm trying, in vain, to verify this result. Please read my question.

Comment: Just notice an improper behavior of `GetInactivePDE`: ``c = IdentityMatrix[2];
α = {x, y}; γ = {y, x^2}; ipde = Inactive[Div][Inactive[Plus][-c . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], Inactive[Times][-α, u[x, y]], γ], {x, y}] == 0; {state} = NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{ipde, DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   u, {x, y} ∈ Disk[]]; NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE@state``, the $(-c ∇u-α u+γ)$ term should be placed in a single $∇·$.

Comment: @xzczd, I'll have a look once I'm back from vacation.

Comment: @xzczd, I had a look. The fact that GetInactivePDE returns a divergence for each term is not wrong per se. No matter how I implement this, there will always be forms where the output is mathematically equivalent but different from what was given on input. I don't think this is a major problem. Do you disagree?

Comment: Well, I disagree. Though the PDEs are mathematically equivalent, the corresponding `NeumannValue`s are different, and one of the most important usage of `GetInactivePDE` (in my view) is helping one to decide the correct `NeumannValue`.

Comment: @xzczd, there should not be any difference.

Comment: @xzczd, this should be equivalent: `Inactive[
   Div][-c . Inactive[Grad][u[x], {x}] - \[Alpha]*
    u[x] + \[Gamma], {x}] == 
 Inactive[Div][-c . Inactive[Grad][u[x], {x}], {x}] + 
  Inactive[Div][-\[Alpha]*u[x], {x}] + Inactive[Div][\[Gamma], {x}] ==
  NeumannValue`

Comment: Yeah, but when `Times` is `Inactive`d, the situation is different, I elaborate the issue in this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271385/1871

Comment: OK, thanks I'll look at that a bit later.

Comment: Oops, I see, it's indeed not wrong. (It's $\nabla \color{orange}{\cdot} (-\alpha  u)$ v.s. $\beta \color{orange}{\cdot} \nabla u$. ) But still, I'd argue if $−c∇u−αu+γ$ is in a single $\nabla \cdot$, the output will be much easier to follow.

Comment: @xzczd, yeah, would be nice but it's not easy to get and I'd rather spend my time fixing more serious issues. Thanks for checking this again and also for reporting it.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if you are aware that this is documented in details.

The problem is that the informations are dispatched over the documentation of `PDECoefficentData` and `InitializePDECoefficients`.

your code :

```
{state} = 
  NDSolve`ProcessEquations[
   With[{u = u[x, y]}, {-2 D[u, y, y] - 3 D[u, x, x] == 1, 
     DirichletCondition[u == 0, True]}], u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];

data = state["FiniteElementData"]["PDECoefficientData"];

data["All"]
(*{{{{1}},{{{{0},{0}}}}},{{{{{3,0},{0,2}}}},{{{{0},{0}}}},{{{{0,0}}}},\
{{0}}},{{{0}}},{{{0}}}}*)
```

The `PDECoefficentData` documentation explains this :

```
data["ConvectionCoefficients"]
data["DampingCoefficients"]
data["MassCoefficients"]
data["LoadCoefficients"]
(* etc ... *)
```

> {{{{0, 0}}}}

> {{0}}

> {{0}}

> {{1}}

`InitializePDECoefficients` documentation :

[image]

The `DampingCoefficients` and `MassCoefficients` are explained beyond.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the **Details** section of `InitializePDECoefficients`… but I think it'll be good to have a function that can generate the formal PDE automatically, checking the table in the document is still a bit painful.

Comment: It took me a while to notice this too (I don't rememder exactly, but it was after having read the tutorials).

Answer (score 5):

The problem has been resolved [by user21](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225841/1871). I'd like to add a wrapper for `` NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE `` to make it easier to use:

```
ClearAll[checkFormalPDE]

toeq[sys_] := 
  Replace[Flatten@{sys}, 
   expr : Except[_Equal | _DirichletCondition | _PeriodicBoundaryCondition] :> 
    expr == 0, {1}];

SetAttributes[checkFormalPDE, HoldAll]; 

With[{pe = NDSolve`ProcessEquations, gip = NDSolve`FEM`GetInactivePDE},
 checkFormalPDE[(head : NDSolve | NDSolveValue | NDEigenvalues | NDEigensystem)[sys_,
     depend_, domain__, n___Integer, rest : OptionsPattern[]]] :=
   Module[{state = Sow@First@pe[sys // toeq, depend, domain, rest]}, state // gip]];
```

### Usage

Simply wrap it on `NDSolve`/`NDSolveValue`/`NDEigenvalues`/`NDEigensystem`:

```
checkFormalPDE@
 NDSolve[With[{u = u[x, y]}, {-2 D[u, y, y] - 3 D[u, x, x] == 1, 
    DirichletCondition[u == 0, True]}], u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
(* {-1 + Inactive[Div][(-{{3, 0}, {0, 2}} . Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}]} *)
```

Comment: Nice. Might be foos for the function repository?

Comment: @user21 Submitted for review :) .

Comment: Great, please share the link once it is live.